# ImportError: cannot import name 'AppiumOptions' from 'appium.webdriver.webdriver'

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, webdriver, appium

I'm  using the below and trying to open an android app using appium.

```
from appium import webdriver
from typing import Any, Dict
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy
from appium.webdriver.webdriver import AppiumOptions

cap: Dict[str, Any] = {
    'platformName': 'Android',
    'deviceName': 'FLex',
    'app': '/home/administrator/Downloads/FlexQa.apk',
    'appPackage': 'com.flexsalary',
    'automationName': 'UiAutomator2'
}
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:4723/'

driver = webdriver.Remote(url, options=AppiumOptions().load_capabilities(cap))

el = driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value='//android.widget.Button[@content-desc="ApplyNow"]')
el.click()

driver.quit()
```

I want to open the app and I have tried updating the appium and I'm expecting to open the app and click on the button using the xpath

Answer (score 0):

You need to install:

```
pip install Appium-Python-Client==3.1.0
```

I am able to successfully use

```
from appium.webdriver.webdriver import AppiumOptions
```

with `3.1.0` version

```
from appium import webdriver
from typing import Any, Dict
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy
from appium.webdriver.webdriver import AppiumOptions
```